# CPUMiner won't compile

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to compile a CPUMiner program, but get errors which I don't know what to do about. I am compiling as said here:

http://www.return1.at/bitcoin-miner-ubuntu/

The error is:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/tomino/_software/cpuminer':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And error in config.log:

```
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 
configure:3320: $? = 0
configure:3309: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3320: $? = 4
configure:3309: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3320: $? = 4
configure:3340: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3362: gcc -03   conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-03'
```

Please help someone. Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't download software from some random site.  What's return1.at ?  use   https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer   not that just **because** it's on github that means it's **not** a trojan, but...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found the problem. It is rather stupid...

In tutorial they say to run:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-O3"
```

But the flag **IS NOT** 03 (zero three) but O3 (o three)
Thats all...